# Understanding shared SQLAlchemy session between Flask app and celery task

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, celery

I have problem understanding this. So I have a flask app integrated with SQLAlchemy and celery. Because the celery task is **attached** to the Flask app, it can take advantage of the ORM session and operate the DB. The confusion here is that I always think of an ORM session as a MySQL connection. I don't think two different process (or green thread) is supposed to share a DB connection. There is probably some misunderstanding from my side. Please shed some light.